# Replace special characters (Ç, <90>, ½, Ô, ¶, Ø) in Unix AIX

Tags: unix, special-characters, aix

I have a set of special characters to replace with some known characters.  When I run the below command, I could see the special characters on screen. 
`LC_ALL=C grep --color='auto' -o -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" data.txt`

When I grep using a nearby word, the special characters are seen as **L▒G▒RE** 
In vi editor, they seen as **L<90>GÔRE**. 
Other special characters I have **Ç, <90>, ½, Ô, ¶, Ø** and so on.

I tried the below tr but they get replaced with spaces as per the command.

```
cat data.txt | tr -c '\000-\177' ' '
```

I would like to replace them all with some meaningful characters.  For example, **<90> as E** and **Ô as O** and some with just spaces.

```
grep a_nearby_word data.txt | od -c
```

```
**0001260  L 220   G 324   R   E***
```

Note:  Pasting just the hex for the word.

Applying the above with tr didn't work.  Instead, it replaced all the text with Es.

```
cat data.txt | tr -c '\220' 'E'
```

Comment: Do you know how the "special characters" should be displayed? Should these be some non-english characters, e.g. accented characters? Maybe you simply have to choose the correct character encoding. Or maybe you can change the encoding with tools like `recode` or `iconv`. Show the output of `grep a_nearby_word data.txt | od -c`. Please don't use comments to answer, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Please copy&paste both the exact `grep`...| od...` command you actually used and the exact output. Better show a bit more output. Instead of using `grep` you could also extract a few lines of text. It may help to show some more data for possible guessing the encoding. I tried to fix the formatting, but you might have mixed the output with formatting characters like `**`. Please check and fix (or better extend) the output.

Comment: Off: In Linux, there is a program called `unaccent`.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Since `unaccent` requires a *`charset`*  argument the character set of the input file must be known or guessed. (The same is valid for conversion tools `recode` or `iconv`.) Unfortunately the question does not show enough input data to guess the character set. @SanthoshRam Please [edit] your question and add background information about the input file. What application/command was used to create the file on what OS? Should it contain text only? In what language? Show some output of `LC_ALL=C grep -C 1 -P "[\x80-\xFF]" data.txt`. Maybe someone can guess the character set.

Comment: @Bodo Very true. My guess is utf8, but cannot be sure.